# How to set a subscription default price in Play console?

Tags: android, subscription, google-play-console

I am pretty sure that in the past there was a field to set a default price for subscriptions (like with in-app-purchases, the default price is used to generate local prices for the app in other countries).
However I can't find this field now.
I really hope that I don't need to set prices for all countries manually...

Comment: Yes, In Subscription tab, seems like i need to fill those manually.

Answer (score 10):

OK I have found it.
Click on "update prices"->choose all countries->click on "set price"->set the price.
The UI issue is that the button "update prices" doesn't look like a button...

Comment: So the solution is only for existing base plan. :(

Comment: I can't find what you mention "update prices". may be it is removed by google play

Comment: Where is the "update prices" option?

Comment: It says "Set prices" next to "Manage country/region availability". It's grey. I wasted  30 mins trying to figure it out. This is the worst UI ever.

Comment: Wow, they really need to sort that button, it looks like a label

Comment: A case of bad UI design by google, everyone misses it

Answer (score 6):

To set one price for multiple regions at once:

Go to: Subscriptions/Edit base plan

Tap "Set price" This is a button but it doesn't look like one!

[image]

Comment: I think that was the label 

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty easy. Once you get to the 'base plan' just look for 'set prices', when you click on it you can then mark all countries, then you can add one price in your native currency and it will propagate the prices for all countries converted appropriately.

From there you can edit individually ie. Lower the price for your home country, be a good guy.