# Set a subscription default price in Play console one time

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, google-play-console

I need to add subscription price one time for all countries. like inapp product you can set the price for default currency and it's reflected automatically for all other countries.

I found "Add base plan" in google play console, inside it I can edit price for each country alone.
as in this picture:
[image]
Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72570275/2828651) answer but can't be applied , my be it's changed by google play.
Otherwise, I 've to change price for each country, which will take too long time to convert then fill in.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it as below:

1- click on set price ( it's dimm, but ok click it).
as highlighted
[image]

2-check below highlighted box (all country  / region):
[image]

3-click on set price again ( below the page).
[image]

4-fill in price and hit update as below:
[image]

Comment: OMG Thank you -- Google Play's new subscription setup is horrible compared to the old way.

Comment: Thanks so much, I spent way too long trying to find this option

Comment: Thank you for this.  What an absolutely horrible UI/UX by google.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  We updated the UI to hopefully make the 'Set prices' button more discoverable.